# InvocationTargetException caused by SWTError ("no more handles")?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, runtime-error, handle

I am experiencing a strange error. I have an Eclipse 3.7.2-based RCP application.

When starting it from my run configuration, it throws an `InvocationTargetException` which is caused by an `SWTError` (stacktrace below). In the stacktrace there is the message "*Could not instantiate splash*", however, the splash is shown without any problems.

The only line of code from my own code base in the stacktrace is from the `Application.class`:

```
int returnCode = PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(display, 
                     new ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor());
```

It is true, in `ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor` I have some dubious `SWT`-based code calling, e.g., the **internal** (evil!) `IDEWorkbenchPlugin`:

```
@Override
public void initialize(IWorkbenchConfigurer configurer) {
  super.initialize(configurer);
  IDE.registerAdapters();

  final String ICONS_PATH = "icons/full/";
    final String PATH_OBJECT = ICONS_PATH + "obj16/";
    Bundle ideBundle = Platform.getBundle(IDEWorkbenchPlugin.IDE_WORKBENCH);
    declareWorkbenchImage(configurer, ideBundle, IDE.SharedImages.IMG_OBJ_PROJECT,
        PATH_OBJECT + "prj_obj.gif", true);
    declareWorkbenchImage(configurer, ideBundle, IDE.SharedImages.IMG_OBJ_PROJECT_CLOSED,
        PATH_OBJECT + "cprj_obj.gif", true);
}

public IAdaptable getDefaultPageInput()  {
    IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
    return workspace.getRoot();
}

public WorkbenchWindowAdvisor createWorkbenchWindowAdvisor(IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer) {
    return new ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor(configurer);
}

public String getInitialWindowPerspectiveId() {
    return PERSPECTIVE_ID;
}

private void declareWorkbenchImage(IWorkbenchConfigurer configurer_p, Bundle ideBundle, String symbolicName,
        String path, boolean shared) {
           URL url = ideBundle.getEntry(path);
           ImageDescriptor desc = ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(url);
           configurer_p.declareImage(symbolicName, desc, shared);
}
```

**However**, even when I comment out that code and leave the `initialize()` method with only the call `super.initialize(configurer);`, the application starts just fine, but still throws the errors...

Run from Kepler, on OpenJDK 1.7, Ubuntu 13.10 (x86_64).

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2014-04-11 13:19:36.870
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2014-04-11 13:19:37.167
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.getSplashShell(WorkbenchPlugin.java:1327)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$8.run(Workbench.java:760)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createSplashWrapper(Workbench.java:806)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2528)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at my.Application.start(Application.java:44)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
Caused by: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4308)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4197)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4168)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:466)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.createHandle(Shell.java:701)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.createWidget(Widget.java:412)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createWidget(Control.java:570)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.createWidget(Scrollable.java:152)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.createWidget(Decorations.java:240)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.<init>(Shell.java:281)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.internal_new(Shell.java:386)
... 28 more
Root exception:
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4308)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4197)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4168)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:466)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.createHandle(Shell.java:701)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.createWidget(Widget.java:412)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createWidget(Control.java:570)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.createWidget(Scrollable.java:152)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.createWidget(Decorations.java:240)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.<init>(Shell.java:281)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.internal_new(Shell.java:386)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.getSplashShell(WorkbenchPlugin.java:1327)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$8.run(Workbench.java:760)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createSplashWrapper(Workbench.java:806)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2528)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at my.Application.start(Application.java:44)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-04-11 13:19:37.177
!MESSAGE Could not instantiate splash
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4308)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4197)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4168)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:466)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.createHandle(Shell.java:701)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.createWidget(Widget.java:412)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createWidget(Control.java:570)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.createWidget(Scrollable.java:152)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.createWidget(Decorations.java:240)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.<init>(Shell.java:281)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.internal_new(Shell.java:386)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.getSplashShell(WorkbenchPlugin.java:1327)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$8.run(Workbench.java:760)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createSplashWrapper(Workbench.java:806)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2528)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at my.Application.start(Application.java:44)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with my application. I've built the product and when I run it (with `-consoleLog`): No `SWTError`s at all. Must be the IDE...

Comment: We hit that in our application as well.  It was from creating too many composites at one time.

Comment: @SteveSarcinella: Yes, that's what I thought it would be, not disposing of SWT widgets correctly, but it isn't my product (the same use case path doesn't throw the exception)... Maybe a bug in the IDE somewhere?

Comment: I would guess as much, we use Eclipse RCP 4.3/4.4 and have noticed the same behavior.  It's not just composites though, colors and fonts will due the same (these need to be manually disposed).  It seems that eclipse does have a limit on it's number of handles, where as the OS doesn't have as low of a limit.  Not much help I can offer I'm afraid :/